# how to insert the JscrollPane to

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Eclipse .I am trying to insert Jscrollpane to Jpanel. I was successfully inserted using Windows builder. But its not working.I searched in net also. I didnt get clear idea.I inserted my code here. Please check it and give me the suggestion.

```
public class Text {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Text window = new Text();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Text() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 676, 254);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 11));
        button.setBounds(252, 148, 95, 41);
        panel.add(button);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "Tax", TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(255, 69, 0)));
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(204, 255, 204));
        panel_1.setBounds(14, 31, 561, 95);
        panel.add(panel_1);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Name");
        label.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        label.setBounds(179, 25, 33, 14);
        panel_1.add(label);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setBounds(236, 22, 145, 20);
        panel_1.add(textField);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Percentage(%)");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        label_1.setBounds(140, 56, 72, 14);
        panel_1.add(label_1);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(236, 53, 145, 20);
        panel_1.add(textField_1);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("*");
        label_2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label_2.setBounds(214, 25, 12, 14);
        panel_1.add(label_2);

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("*");
        label_3.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label_3.setBounds(214, 56, 12, 14);
        panel_1.add(label_3);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't even contain the words `JScrollPane`

Comment: Nothing a layout manager probably wouldn't fix. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for starters

Comment: And [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) might be of some help as well

Comment: thanks for replying all. I already  change my layout in my coding but its not working.

Comment: In Netbeans IDE its working perfectly. But Problem came in Eclipse. I dont know why/ Please give the Suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

I would follow what others recommended and provided links for you to study how to use scroll panes, but in your example I had done small modification ,

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(650,250);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(dim);

    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added this code. The Scrollpane was added. while running the scrollpane is not working.

Comment: you have to add more controls to the JPanel that exceed the Jpanel width and height for the scroll pane to scroll.

Comment: I added a change to the code that can help, setting the preferred size to it so that you add more controls to the JPanel that exceed the scrollPane size

Comment: I added more controls  and i was updated the coding. But its not working. If i update your code my designing was changing. I designed my form in Absolute lay out.

Comment: Thank you for all. Now i prefer the Group layout. Now its working fine.